# Salesforce Date Formula doesn't show proper results

Tags: formula, date

Hi Salesforce enthusiasts!

I need to troubleshoot existing formula in my organization (or create a simpler one) "Contract Renewal Date" (see below) which is supposed to show the date:

```
Contract_Start_Date__c + Contract_duration__c (in month) - Cancellation_Period__c (in month)
```

Example: Contract starts 1 January 2021, duration is 12 months, the cancellation period is 3 months, The expected result of "Contract Renewal Date" would be 1st October 2021

Problem:

somehow this formula works perfectly for almost all Opportunities except a few of them (mostly when the contract starts in February and always when the cancellation period is 1.5 months)
Thanks for your help!

```
Contract_Renewal_Date__c =

DATE (

/YEAR/ YEAR ( Contract_Start_Date__c ) + FLOOR ( (MONTH ( Contract_Start_Date__c ) + Contract_duration__c - Cancellation_Period__c - 1)/12),

/MONTH/ CASE ( MOD ( MONTH ( Contract_Start_Date__c )+Contract_duration__c - Cancellation_Period__c, 12 ),0,12,MOD ( MONTH ( Contract_Start_Date__c )+Contract_duration__c - Cancellation_Period__c, 12 )),

/DAY/ Contract_Renewal_Date_Day__c )

where Contract_Renewal_Date_Day__c=

MIN ( DAY ( Contract_Start_Date__c ), CASE ( MOD ( MONTH ( Contract_Start_Date__c )+Contract_duration__c - Cancellation_Period__c,12 ) ,9,30,4,30,6,30,11,30,2,

/* return max days for February dependent on if end date is leap year */ IF ( MOD ( YEAR ( Contract_Start_Date__c ) + FLOOR ( (MONTH ( Contract_Start_Date__c ) + Contract_duration__c - Cancellation_Period__c)/12) , 400 ) = 0 || ( MOD ( YEAR ( Contract_Start_Date__c ) + FLOOR ( (MONTH ( Contract_Start_Date__c ) + Contract_duration__c - Cancellation_Period__c)/12) , 4 ) = 0 && MOD ( YEAR ( Contract_Start_Date__c ) + FLOOR ( (MONTH ( Contract_Start_Date__c ) + Contract_duration__c - Cancellation_Period__c)/12) , 100 ) <> 0 ) , 29,28)

,31 ) )
```

Comment: You mention 1.5 months as a valid value in those duration/period fields? Is there any prevention/logic/validation to prevent 1.2 or any permutation? There's an [addmonths](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5#ADDMONTHS) function that makes this pretty simple if the fields were truly just a whole number of months, but not if you're storing partial months (storing days in that scenario might make more sense).

Comment: Awesome, thanks, will try the addmonths function!

Comment: @KrisGoncalves that solved my problem, thank you! Can you repost your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [ADDMONTHS](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5#ADDMONTHS) function that would make this simpler assuming your duration and period fields are whole numbers.

[image]

I will point out the highlighted point about how it will function if the month it lands on doesn't have the day, it'll take the last valid day of the month.

```
ADDMONTHS(Contract_Start_Date__c, (Contract_duration__c - Cancellation_Period__c))
```

That's me making an assumption above that the `Contract_Duration__c` will be larger than `Cancellation_Period__c`. If that is not true, an IF statement can help handle different scenarios or edge cases.

```
IF(Contract_duration__c > Cancellation_Period__c,
    ADDMONTHS(Contract_Start_Date__c, (Contract_duration__c - Cancellation_Period__c)),
    ADDMONTHS(Contract_Start_Date__c, (Cancellation_Period__c- Contract_duration__c))
)
```

Comment: epic, thank you!